# how to watch DVDs on my Captivate

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, video

I would like to rip and watch a DVD on my new Samsung Galaxy S (Captivate variety) handset.  Sometimes I get a goofy sci-fi on Netflix that I would like to watch but the wife wouldn't bother. So I want to rip a copy to my PC and watch it later on my captivate.  What is the best format/method/player for me?

Comment: This question is no longer relevant for me since Netflix now streams all the SciFi I want and I don't have to worry about the DVDs.  Still relevant for anyone who has DVDs that they want to watch on a phone though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) is a good program to rip and convert DVD video (it may not work on certain copy protected DVDs but that's a topic for another SE).

The stock video player plays H.264 .mp4 videos well ([here are the supported formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)).  You can actually just use the iphone/ipod preset in handbreak, just change the width of the video to the height dimension of your phone (so you can watch it in landscape, on the Droid it's 854 px).  It will output a .m4v format which technically isn't supported but it will play because it's not drm'd by itunes.

If you prefer another format like .avi, then you'll need another player like [RockPlayer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/rockplayer-universal/com.redirectin.rockplayer.android.unified) which supports many more video formats:

> avi mkv rmvb mp4 mov wmv asf wma wav
>   mpg ts mpa dvd au mp3 mid ivf aiff ogm
>   ogg cda flic d2v aac roq flac drc dsm
>   swf pls pmp

Answer (score 2):

'Re' download the movie on line and just copy the divx files to your phone. Most movies should just work with the default movie player (which is really great on the SGS)

Ripping a movie takes a lot of time/knowledge just downloading it is easy and probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

[Meridian](http://www.appbrain.com/app/meridian-media-player-lite/org.iii.romulus.meridian) is a pretty popular media player.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Foxreal DVD Ripper, which can convert any DVD to Samsung Galaxy S easily. What's more, it customize the best video format for Samsung Galaxy S to help u get the best visual experience, you can try it, good luck!

Comment: How about a link?