# Play DVDs on an Android device (preferably Google TV) as DVDs without conversion

Tags: video, usb-on-the-go, media-player

I have a collection of DVDs I own and have ripped and would like to play on my Android device.  I want them to play on my Android device *exactly like a DVD* -- with menus, etc.  I can easily do this on my PC with various DVD playing software (i.e.  VLC Media Player).  I do *not* want to convert the file to DivX or MP4 or whatever. (as the answers to those questions suggest)  I do not want to lose the menuing and the scene selection, etc.  Instead, I want a full 4.5 GB rip stored on my hard drive and I want to "point at that" (and over the network to boot).

I saw these two questions:

- [Can android phones play DVD-format movies over WIFI?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-android-phones-play-dvd-format-movies-over-wifi)
- [how to watch DVDs on my Captivate](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/how-to-watch-dvds-on-my-captivate)

However, neither of these questions addresses what I would like to do.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no DVD-player software for Android. Nothing that can emulate a DVD experience from a network (or even local) location.

What are you needing from a *full DVD experience* that you cannot get by transcoding the movie to a portable format? Scene selection? That's really just a way to visually access chapters in the movie. I've used [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to transcode my movies for my Droid X2 while keeping the chapter markers.

If you need things like different languages and subtitles, HandBrake can include those as well into your MP4/M4V output.

Comment: this workarund is no direct but complex and time consuming. Conceptually a DVD reader should be able to be accessed through USB OTG and then data should be accessible by software.